# How to reply a job interview while accepting it

Tags: attracting-clients, communication, negotiation

This question is the second trickest question that need to be answered. When you get a job invite on oDesk or elance, what is the right way to reply so the job is yours? I typically reply as

> Thank you for the invite, I have read your invitation and interested in it. My Skype is abc, I hope to talk to you there and take the hiring further.

Is there a better format to write me reply?

Comment: If there was a formula, everyone would use it. There is no formula. Talk to the client about their project and why you are interested in it at what you can contribute. You want them to pick you out of everyone and the only way you can do that is to prove you know your stuff.

Answer (score 3):

The "must" you have to do is to thank for the invitation. If I am not mistaken, this can be done either "Thank you for the invitation" or "Thanks for the invitation".

After that you do like in other bids: ask about project details, ask about project specs, deadline, and everything else you usually ask.

As Stacey says, there are no magic words.

Comment: Very good points. Heck, it may depend on the client how long the response is

Comment: You might want to check out Freelancers Union (https://www.freelancersunion.org/)  they are all about getting paid and they have a lot of information on this subject.